# Ubuntu and Debian have different character encoding for filenames

Tags: debian, ubuntu, filenames, character-encoding

I am mounting a NFS filesystem to a Debian, an Amazon Linux and an Ubuntu file system and they are showing different character encoding for file name.

An example file is displayed as follows in the corresponding systems:

Ubuntu:

```
スクリーンショット-2018-01-11-11.28.19.png
```

Debian:

```
'$'\343\202\271\343\202\257\343\203\252\343\203\274\343\203\263\343\202\267\343\203\247\343\203\203\343\203\210''-2018-01-11-11.28.19.png'
```

Amazon Linux:

```
???????????????????????????-2018-01-11-11.28.19.png
```

The problem I am having is, that I am running a Wordpress server in these and the Debian instance is returning errors because it cannot find the image file, which I am assuming is because of the filename difference.

Why there is such a different in the filename encoding between these distributions, even though all 3 of them are Debian based?
And is there a fix for the Debian system?

output of `locale`:
Note that although `locale` of Amazon Linux and Debian are the same, the filenames are displayed differently.

Debian:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Ubuntu:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Amazon Linux:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Thank you.

Comment: Character set mappings are managed through locales. Please add the output of `locale` for each of the three systems to your question. (Each one should be about 15 lines.)

Comment: In addition to what @roaima wrote, also consider https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56021_01/html/E55851/gokvz.html

Comment: @roaima Thank you. I added the output of `locale`.

Comment: That's great. Almost there. Please could you also add the output of `locale -a`, again from each system. The previous command showed the currently selected (or intended) locale. This one shows the available locales. I suspect that `en_US.UTF-8` is not available on your two problematic servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the set of available locales and the selected intended locale. The `locale -a` command will show the available locales, and `locale` shows the currently selected locale.

Ubuntu: `C.UTF-8`
Debian: `en_US.UTF-8`
Amazon: `en_US.UTF-8`

The `en_US.UTF-8` locale is not available on Debian or Amazon Linux. The `locale -a` command will show whether `C.UTF-8` is available there.

If you run this command (as root) on the Debian and Amazon Linux servers, you can not only select the set of locales to generate but then on the next screen you will get the option to select the system-default locale.

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

You should either ensure that `en_US.UTF-8` is built on the Debian and Amazon Linux systems, or that (assuming `C.UTF-8` is already selected there) `C.UTF-8` is selected as the system default.

Without one of the many UTF-8 locales being selected, the user interface cannot know that you expect the byte string `$'\343\202\271\343\202\257\343\203\252\343\203\274\343\203\263\343\202\267\343\203\247\343\203\203\343\203\210'` to be interpreted and displayed as `スクリーンショット`.